# add event for sub children in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just a little help for me here with jquery.
This is my problem. I have a list

```
<ul>
  <li>
      <p>Name</p>
      <a href="#">Delete</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

the 'Delete' event click was initiation in jquery when load page. So the issue now, i'd like to add an element `<li></li>` which contain children like above. I used jquery to create the tag 'li' contain children, then 'prepend' to the 'ul'.
The problem is, i can not call 'delete' event on new item. Somebody help me please

Comment: Please provide the javascript that adds the li to the ul and the javascript that adds the listener to Delete link.

Comment: var contentToAdd = '

<li>
      <p>Name</p>
      <a href="#">Delete</a>
</li>';

$('ul').prepend(contentToAdd);

So now, how can i add event for 'Delete'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/wGFwU/)**

```
var contentToAdd = ' <li> <p>Name</p> <a href="#">Delete</a> </li>';
$('ul').prepend(contentToAdd);

$('ul').on('click','a', function(){
    alert('click');
});
```

Comment: Oh, just a little bit more to work, It likes your way
var contentToAdd = ' <li> <p>Name</p> <a href="#">Delete</a> </li>';
contentToAdd = $(contentToAdd);
contentToAdd.find('a').click(function(){
   // do here
});
$('ul').prepend(contentToAdd);

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're most probably using .click or bind('click') to attach the click event handler to the element. This is fine if all of the elements exist at the time when you attach the event, if however you create new elements that match that same selector, they will not get that event attached.

You need to use the delegate() or .on() method to attach the event to all elements that are current on the page or are appended to the page after they're set up.

An example of a delegate that catches the click event and appends a new element that you can click and see that the same event is attached to each new part of the DOM that matches the selector.

```
$('#list').delegate('a','click',function() {
    alert('Click event fired - Adding a new element to test!');
    $('ul').append('<li><p>Name</p><a href="#">Delete</a></li>');
    return false;
});
```

Or using the newer .on method:

```
$('#list').on('click','a',function() {
    alert('Click event fired - Adding a new element to test!');
    $('ul').append('<li><p>Name</p><a href="#">Delete</a></li>');
    return false;
});
```

`$('#list')` is what my example uses to denote the `<ul>`, but you could just as easily use `$('ul')` if you don't want to put an id or class on the list.

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sYprh/1/)

Comment: Incorrect, it has been superseded by the .on() method, but only .live() was deprecated http://api.jquery.com/delegate/.

Comment: Not a problem, I did a double check myself =)

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this jQuery example:
(one of the last examples on http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
p { background:yellow; font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer;
    padding:5px; }
p.over { background: #ccc; }
span { color:red; }
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Click me!</p>
<span></span>
<script>
var count = 0;
$("body").on("click", "p", function(){
  $(this).after("<p>Another paragraph! "+(++count)+"</p>");
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

which means in your case you need something like:

```
$("ul").on("click", "a", function(e){
    // delete logic goes here
})
```

Comment: Yes, i can know this one. But this event was ad when load page. So with my problem, i create the 
<li>
    ....
</li>
in the jquery. 
Ex: var abc = '<li>
                  <p>Name</p>
                  <a>Delete</a>
               </li>';
So how can i add event for element a?

Answer (score 0):

Add the click listener on the UL rather than the a's themselves. This way it will automatically detect clicks to newly added items as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul").on("click li > a", function() {
        $(this).closest("li").remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: your syntax is wrong, should be `"click", "li > a", function(){...}`

Comment: Just a different syntax, but produces the same result since jquery uses sizzle. - http://jsfiddle.net/ME7Yq/

Comment: Damn, I didn't know that :) But good to keep your event separated from your element selector?

Comment: I am used of that syntax from using Backbone, you declare you events and handlers using that syntax. events: {"event selector": "handleClickEvent"}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to do so,

> The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set
>   of elements in the jQuery object

```
$(document).on("click", "ul li a"), function(){
    //your code here
});
```

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/Pm54N/)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, given that ".on" doesn't meet your requirements, perhaps something like:

```
$element = $('<li><p>Name</p><a href="#">Delete</a></li>');
$element.find("a").click(function(){ 
    //call your delete function
})

$("ul").prepend($element);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
$("ul").on("click", "a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Why dont you use jquery templating.
You can define a text/template and iterate over it to get your desired result.
an example:
**THIS IS YOUR SCRIPT**
<script id="movieTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li><b>${Name}</b> was released in ${ReleaseYear}.</li>
</script>

**THIS IS THE JQUERY TEMPLATE**
<script type="text/javascript">
    var movies = [
        { Name: "The Red Violin", ReleaseYear: "1998" },
        { Name: "Eyes Wide Shut", ReleaseYear: "1999" },
        { Name: "The Inheritance", ReleaseYear: "1976" }
    ];

    // Render the template with the movies data and insert
    // the rendered HTML under the "movieList" element
    $( "#movieTemplate" ).tmpl( movies )
        .appendTo( "#movieList" );
</script>

**THIS IS YOUR HTML**
<ul id="movieList"></ul>
```

More examples : 
http://blog.reybango.com/2010/07/09/not-using-jquery-javascript-templates-youre-really-missing-out/